Element <module> can be built without a corresponding pom.xml file?
Specified in the pom.xml file of the m2e project:
<module>org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit</module>


https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/pom.xml line 44

However, there is no pom.xml file in the org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit directory, so how does it build?

That's built via POM-less Tycho: https://vogella.com/blog/pom-less-tycho-enhanced/
